# How can i add RadWindow from ContentPage to RadWindowManager in MasterPage?

Tags: ajax, telerik, radwindow

I have the RadWindowManager in MasterPage (MasterPage.aspx):

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="MasterRadWindowManager" runat="server" VisibleStatusbar="false"
        DestroyOnClose="false">

    </telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

How can i add RadWindow from ContentPage (Default.aspx) to the RadWindowManager in MasterPage?

Answer (score 2):

RadWindow:

```
RadWindow radwindowNews = new RadWindow();
radwindowNews.ID = "RadWindow1";
radwindowNews.Width = 820;
radwindowNews.Height = 600;
radwindowNews.Modal = true;
radwindowNews.ReloadOnShow = true;
radwindowNews.AutoSize = false;
radwindowNews.ShowContentDuringLoad = false;
radwindowNews.Behaviors = WindowBehaviors.Close;
```

Add the RadWindow:

```
RadWindowManager radManager =
    (RadWindowManager)this.Master.FindControl("MasterRadWindowManager");
radManager.Windows.Add(radwindowNews);
```